# What is the most succinct way to animate the drawing of an SVG shape on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've been working on this (seemingly) simple little enhancement for a site for too long and I decided to ask for help.

I would like the outline of my contact form fields to animate and draw around the input area on focus, as in this video http://tinypic.com/r/ofrb4h/9

I have figured out a way to animate the svg, but not how to put that on top of my form, and also I'm just not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Here's the html code and the CodePen to go along with it:

```
<div class="container-div">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 444 501" class="blue">
        <path class="outline-path" id="outline" fill="none" stroke="teal" stroke-width="3"
         d="M 385.00,193.50
            C 404.00,195.75 406.25,228.00 385.25,230.75
              385.25,230.75 67.00,230.25 67.00,230.25
              46.50,228.75 45.25,197.25 67.25,193.25
              67.25,193.25 385.00,193.50 385.00,193.50 Z" 
         />
    </svg>
</div>

<form class="contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Name:</p> <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-inline name-input" name="name"
            id="name" placeholder="Cal Critter" oninput="nameFunction()"/>
        <br>

        <p>Email:</p> 
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-inline email-input" name="email"
            id="email" placeholder="reachme@email.com" oninput="emailFunction()"/>
        <br>

        <p>Rough Budget:</p>
        <div class="selectdiv"><label for="budget">Budget</label><select name="budget" id="budget"
                class="budget-input">
                <option class="select-dropdown" value="Less Than $5,000" selected>Less Than $5,000</option>
                <option class="select-dropdown" value="$5,000 - $20,000">$5,000 - $20,000</option>
                <option class="select-dropdown" value="$20,000 - $50,000">$20,000 - $50,000</option>
                <option class="select-dropdown" value="$50,000 - $100,000">$50,000 - $100,000</option>
                <option class="select-dropdown" value="$100,000 - $500,000">$100,000 - $500,000</option>
                <option class="select-dropdown" value="More Than $500,000">More Than $500,000</option>
                <option class="select-dropdown" value="?">?</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>

        <p>Message:</p> 
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-inline  message-input" name="message"
            id="message" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Tell us a little about your project here..."
            oninput="messageFunction()">
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="" type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

https://codepen.io/AshleyMSherwood/pen/bREawx

I'd really appreciate any suggestions

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the effect on focus you can use this code.

```
var inputBox = document.querySelector('input');
inputBox.addEventListener('focus', function(){
   document.querySelector('path').classList.add('outline-path');
   document.querySelector('.container-div').style.display = "block";
})
```

add this code to remove effect on 'blur'.

```
inputBox.addEventListener('blur', function(){
   document.querySelector('.container-div').style.display = "none";
   document.querySelector('path').classList.remove('outline-path');
})
```